# SQL Server transactional replication: do we need to drop-and-recreate subscription if we drop articles from the publication

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I'm using SQL server 2012 enterprise edition. I've set up a SQL transaction replication between two servers.
And now I want to drop some articles from the publication.
I'm not sure whether there are some special considerations/actions after the articles being removed from publication.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152493.aspx) it says:

> For snapshot or transactional publications, articles can be dropped with no special considerations prior to subscriptions being created. **If an article is dropped after one or more subscriptions is created, the subscriptions must be dropped, recreated, and synchronized**.

However, from my test, after the articles being dropped and snapshot re-created, the subscription can successfully sync the data from publication without any special action.

Can anybody give some help?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following script and I usually don't need to run a full snapshot, or when I run it, it says that the subscribers are ok and there is no need for a snapshot.

```
 --(1)
use [MYDATABASE]
exec sp_dropsubscription @publication = N'MYPUBLICATION', @article = N'MYTABLE', @subscriber = N'all', @destination_db = N'all'
GO

-- (2)
use [MYDATABASE]
exec sp_droparticle @publication = N'MYPUBLICATION', @article = N'MYTABLE', @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have dropped the article, you just need to re-initialise the subscription by recreating the snapshot so it can re-sync.

Please see below for the steps to be taken.

http://blog.extreme-advice.com/2012/11/28/delete-article-from-transactional-replication-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: I think this would be true only if immediate_sync is set to true on the publication. Otherwise, snapshots just sitting around aren't very useful.